# Can you place landmarks in lake?

Tags: tobago

In Tobago there are only few rules when placing huts, palms and statues and implicitly I never placed these landmarks on lake tiles.

Is there any rule or hint saying whether or not they can be placed on lake tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. The only stipulations for landmarks are the following, according to the game setup sheet:

> - Each space may only contain one object.
> - All similar objects must be placed **at least four spaces apart**.
> - Statues may not be placed adjacent to the ocean.

If you're making the choice to not put trees or huts on lake tiles, while it is practical for "realism", there's no rule against it.

Comment: Flotaillas rule!

Comment: I was going to say, a hut on a lake? Seems like paradise.